# Delete file if corresponding file with different extension doesn't exist in subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I have a single folder with a bunch of .rst files, and another folder with a bunch of .md files scattered throughout subdirectories. For every .rst file, I want to check if there is a corresponding .md file with the same name. If there is no corresponding .md file, I want to delete the .rst file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for %%A in (buildfiles\source\*.rst) do if not exist "%%~nA.md" del "%%A"
```

This works as long as the .md files are all in the same directory as the batch file. What I can't figure out is how to get it to search all the subdirectories of a specific folder to find out if the corresponding .md file doesn't exist. For example, this doesn't do quite what I want:

```
for %%A in (buildfiles\source\*.rst) do if not exist "pages\%%~nA.md" del "%%A"
```

because it only searches the specific "pages" folder and not all of its subdirectories.

Edited to add: I have searched the site extensively and I know that /S is normally used to search subdirectories, but it doesn't work when simply tacked on after "if not exist". For example, this gives an error:

```
for %%A in (buildfiles\source\*.rst) do if not exist "pages\%%~nA.md" /S del "%%A"
```

How can I get the "if not exist" part to search in subdirectories?

Comment: Searching sub directories is a relatively common question here, did you try the sites search facility?

Comment: Yes, it's normally done with /s, and I have used it before when copying files between directories. But using it with the "if not exist" part doesn't work. If I just tack it on like this: for %%A in (buildfiles\source\*.rst) do if not exist "pages\%%~nA.md" /S echo(del "%%A") It gives an error "/S is not recognized as an internal or external command."

Answer (score 0):

**Method-1**: Just 1 command line:

`for %%A in (buildfiles\source\*.rst) do (msr -rp pages -l -f "%%~nA.md" && del "%%A")`

- `msr -rp xxx` **&&** `del xxx` means `not found`(return=`%ERRORLEVEL%`=0) **so can** `delete`
- To hide output of `msr.exe` add `> nul` like : `msr -rp pages -l -f "%%~nxA.md" >nul`

**Method-2**: 4 lines: Use `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead of `%ERRORLEVEL%` if you used `SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`

```
for %%A in (buildfiles\source\*.rst) do (
  msr -rp pages -l -f "%%~nA.md" >nul
  if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 del "%%A"
)
```

`msr.exe` / `msr.gcc*` is a single exe tool without dependencies in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory. Docs are built-in, just run it; or get it from above link or https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html.

(Use `msr-Win32.exe` if your windows is a x86/32-bit machine.)

**Add more fast methods**: (above 2 methods scan `page` for each `rst` file in `buildfiles\source`)

Added `nin.exe` which is also in same place as `msr.exe`; Recursive search `buildfiles\source` and `pages` **only 1 time**, by 3 command pipe (2 `msr.exe` + 1 `nin.exe` commands).

- **Method-3**: Generate command(`-o "del xxx"`) and execute `del` ( by `-X`), you can preview genereated `del` commands without `-X`; Hide some output by `-X -PAC`:

  `msr -rp buildfiles\source,pages -l -f "\.(rst|md)$" -PIC | nin nul "([^\\/]+)\.(rst|md)$" -updAC | msr -x buildfiles\source -t "^1\D.*?:\s*(.+)\s*$" -o "del \"$1\"" -X`
- **Method-4**: Get the file list and deleted: (Need to escape each pipe `|` to `^|` in `for` loop, that's why I prefer `-X` like **Method-3** for simple cases)

  `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('msr -rp buildfiles\source,pages -l -f "\.(rst|md)$" -PIC ^| nin nul "([^\\/]+)\.(rst|md)$" -updAC ^| msr -x buildfiles\source -t "^1\D.*?:\s*(.+)\s*$" -o "$1" -PAC') do del %%a`

You can also use `msr -x ".rst" -t "^1\D.*?:\s*(.+)\s*$" -o "$1"` or `msr -t "^1\D.*?:\s*(.+\.rst)\s*$ -o "$1"` instead of `msr -x buildfiles\source -t "^1\D.*?:\s*(.+)\s*$" -o "$1"` to get the orphan `.rst` file (1 time matched).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I need to be able to do this with standard batch file commands. The batch file will be used by multiple people and I can't guarantee they will be able to install your tool.

Comment: @Daeruin : Yes, you're right as these 2 exe files need to be downloaded. For your batch scripts, you can use: `for %%A in (buildfiles\source\*.rst) do ( dir /s /b "pages\%%~nA.md" 2>nul || del "%%A") ` But sorry for the late reply as I was on vacaion. I think you'd probably got the right solution.